# Can I estimate the size of a xml file before writing it?

Tags: python, lxml, filesize, file-writing

I am using the python module **lxml** to write XML files.
The XML has a size tag that refers to its size (bytes).

I'm currently writing each file twice. First I write the file and leave the size tag empty and then I get its size and rewrite it.

The way I'm doing it works fine but I'm wondering if there is a better approach. If I could somehow estimate the XML size before writing it...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is your XML big? First store it as string in some variable, use `len()` to get its size and then write it.

Comment: My XML size has something around 25800 bytes. Using `len()` gives me a different value.

Comment: The string has probably Unicode characters, so the difference is in encoding. UTF-8?

Comment: Yes it has Unicode characters, but after enconding UTF-8 it still gives me a different value.